# Outlook 2010 - C# - Get the account associated to a mail

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, account

I'm creating an Outlook add-in that can save selected emails to an external database.

Using the `Office.IRibbonControl` I can get the list of the selected email, but I need to know to which account those mails are associated.

I mean, if Outlook get messages from `toto@exemple.com` and from `otot@exemple.com`, when I want to save a message I need to know that information.

I can't use the informations like sender / receiver because it can be an outcome like an income email.

Currently, the only I have found is using the current folder path..

```
public void SayHello(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Folder: " + (control.Context as Outlook.Explorer).CurrentFolder.FolderPath,
        "Test",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

But the method isn't good enough. If I open a message (*in a separated window*) and then I change the current folder, it fails.

Also, `Outlook.Explorer.CurrentAccount` does not work as I expected.

So here is my question :
How can I access the related account having a `Outlook.MailItem` object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the parent folder ([`MailItem.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863655.aspx)) of an [`Outlook.MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861252.aspx) to determine its Folder path ([`Folder.FolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863981.aspx)).

```cs
Outlook.Folder parent = MailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
string itemPath = parent.FolderPath;
```

Comment: Thanks, just an another question: Will always the path contains my account email ?

Comment: Yes - [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863981.aspx), it will always contain the folder path for the current item.

Comment: Thanks again :-) And sorry, I'm not used to MSDN, I have some difficulties to find informations on it..